# Javascript Inserting response data into corresponding cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, cell

I have a table set up with the following headers. I have code set up to send ajax request to retrieve JSON data and brings up a dialog with a table when users clicks a button, and then I filter this data so it gives me a the filtered data back (e,g. Kevin). All the above is working good. Now I want to insert this data (Kevin) into the corresponding cell header (e.g. Name) and other data as well (Number->xxx-xxx-xxxx;address->xxx...etc). I want to do this so I make sure the data is inserted into the correct fields. I need to empty the row after user closes the dialog.

Javascript:

```
executeAPI("GetUserInfo.php", "name", callback); // this returns Kevin

function exeCtCoreAPIcallback(result){
   //need to append the result to the corresponding cell header here.

}
```

HTML:

```
         <table id="data-table">
            <thead>
                <tr id="data-row" class="data-header">
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Number</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Is there a way to reference the name of the `<th>` and insert below?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
        var myCellIndex=new Array();
        $(document).ready(function()
                        {
                            //Initialize the name and index mapping
                            var th=$("#data-row > th");
                            for (var i=0;i<th.length;i++)
                            {
                                myCellIndex[th[i].innerHTML]=th[i].cellIndex;
                            }
                        });

        function updateContent(fieldName,content)
        {
            var cellIndex=myCellIndex[fieldName];
            var bodyRow=$("tbody>tr")[0]; // Because you have 1 row in tbody only.
            if (bodyRow.cells.length<=cellIndex) //If the cell not found
            {   
                for (var i=bodyRow.cells.length;i<=cellIndex;i++) //Add all necessary cells.
                    cell=bodyRow.insertCell(i);
            }
            else
                cell=bodyRow.cells[cellIndex]; //Get a appropiate cell
            cell.innerHTML=content;      //Set the cell content.  
        }
        function go()
        {
            var cell;
            updateContent("Name","Kevin");
            updateContent("Number","xxx-xxx-xxxx");
            updateContent("Status","bla bla");
            updateContent("Address","xxx...");
        }           
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="data-table">
          <thead>
            <tr id="data-row" class="data-header">
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Number</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="go()">
    </body>
</html>
```